# Node.js serving over https

Tags: python, node.js, https, python-requests

I'm testing Node.js application over https connection where I created certificates for localhost,

Certificate creation,

```
$ openssl genrsa -out localhost.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -x509 -key localhost.key -out localhost.cert -days 3650 -subj /CN=localhost
```

Use this in server,

```
var options = { 
  key: fs.readFileSync('./localhost.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./localhost.cert'),
};    
var http2 = require('http2');
var app = express();
const server = http2.createSecureServer( options, app);
server.listen({ host: app_host, port: port});
```

## Start the node.js server as,

```
$ node server.js

Tested using simple curl command as,
$ curl -k https://localhost:9000/getcpuinfo
 {"hw": ...}
```

"-k" option is to ignote certificate validation step.

But if I try to use pythons 'requests' module as shown below the request fails,
    $ python
    import requests

> > > requests.get("https://localhost:9000/getcpuinfo")
> > >             requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)

So I used 'verify' option to make the request, it still fails.

> > > requests.get("https://localhost:9000/getcpuinfo", verify=False)
> > >           requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)

What am I doing wrong? How do I workaround this issue using 'requests' module'? Shouldn't 'verify' prevent the check?

Comment: What's in `server.js`? Can you make a minimal server that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Setting up a minimal HTTPS server like in the [`https` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener) and using certificates created as above doesn't replicate your problem. Either there's a bug in the node.js/requests versions you're using, or your `server.js` code has a bug.

Comment: I'm using newer http2 API for the experiment.

Comment: HTTP/2 != HTTPS, it's a completely different protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a utility as part of nghttp2 called 'h2load' which works out of box for both protocols (http/1 and http/2). Thanks for all the answers/hints.

https://nghttp2.org/documentation/h2load-howto.html#basic-usage

Answer (score 0):

You cant generate https certificates over localhost.

Answer (score 0):

The Python requests module does not connect to HTTP/2 servers, it only supports up to HTTP/1.1:

> **Requests** allows you to send *organic, grass-fed* **HTTP/1.1 requests**, without the need for manual labor. There's no need to manually add query strings to your URLs, or to form-encode your POST data. Keep-alive and HTTP connection pooling are 100% automatic, thanks to urllib3.

If you compile curl with HTTP/2 support, then it will work. The curl packages pre-installed on most Linux distros and MacOS aren't and probably won't work.

Since [HTTP/2 support in Node](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_http2) is experimental and client support is pretty bad outside of modern web browsers, I would not suggest you use it at this time unless you're specifically targeting web browsers or want to use a HTTP/2-capable web server that can support both HTTP/2 and HTTPS.

If you do need to connect to HTTP/2 servers from Python, there is the (also unstable) [`hyper` module](https://github.com/Lukasa/hyper) that does connect to a node.js HTTP/2 server. It currently [doesn't allow you to disable certificate verification](https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#ssl-tls-certificate-verification), so it will not be a drop-in replacement for requests.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. I need to think more about this.